# How can I filter on associated objects?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want a filter on included/joined associated models.

```
practice.patients.joins('
  LEFT JOIN appointments on patients.id = appointments.patient_id 
  LEFT JOIN patient_treatments on patients.id = patient_treatments.patient_id
  LEFT JOIN invoices on patients.id = invoices.patient_id
  LEFT JOIN prescription_values on patients.id = prescription_values.patient_id'
  ).where('(appointments.created_at::date between :start_date and :end_date' ,{start_date: start_date, end_date: end_date })
```

I want patients with appointments in this date range.

Comment: So what's with the code? Is it not working?

Comment: are  u added relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load filtered associated objects only using `eager_load`.

Take a look at this example

```
result = [YourModel].patients.eager_load(:appointments).where("appointments.created_at::date between :start_date and :end_date" ,{start_date: Date.yesterday, end_date: Date.today })
```

It will load patients whose appointment is created between *yesterday* and *today* . Also it will load associated appointments in the specified date range.

Try doing

```
result.first.appointments
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
practice.patients.includes(:appointments).where(appointments: { created_at: start_date..end_date }).group("patients.id")
```